# Cannot access Google services through HTTP (only HTTPS)

Tags: macos, ssl, http

I recently reformatted my hard drive and installed OS X 10.10 Yosemite on my Late 2013 Macbook Pro.

So far everything's great, but within the last two days I haven't been able to access any google services through HTTP. Websites that access ajax.googleapi.com or fonts.googleapi.com load extremely slow (because they have to timeout first) and Google, YouTube, Google+, none of it will load unless I put https:// in the front of the URL.

I can't explain this behavior, and was hoping perhaps someone here could.

Here's a cURL to Google:

```
Kevins-MacBook-Pro:~ Kevin$ curl http://google.com
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Kevins-MacBook-Pro:~ Kevin$ curl https://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>`
```

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely not related to your upgrade. I habe no problems with Yosemite:

```
$ curl http://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.ch/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=IQgMVciNLuKX8Qev3oD4Dg">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Check your router/firewall and network.